# How can I create a mapping for two types in ElasticSearch?

Tags: http, elasticsearch, mapping

I would like to index user IDs and tag IDs.

I send a PUT request to `https://ip//elasticsearch/myIndex`

```
{ 
  "mappings" : {
    "users" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {"type": "keyword" }
      }
    },
    "tags" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {"type": "keyword" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I receive this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [myIndex] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [users, tags]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [myIndex] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [users, tags]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 3):

From Elastic 6.x you cannot have more than 1 mapping type. Use a single mapping type. Instead use custom type field. See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_custom_type_field) link and also [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_alternatives_to_mapping_types) link.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @ben5556, you can only have one type per index in elasticsearch 6+. However, you can mimic multiple types per index by including your own "type" field.

`{ 
  "mappings" : {
    "ids" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {"type": "keyword" }
        "type": {"type": "keyword" }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Then when you index a document, you include the "type":

`{
    "type": "user",
    "id": "12345"
}`

This will allow you to filter by type when querying the index (using a termsQuery). Which is all elasticsearch was really doing behind the scenes for you anyways back when it supported multiple types.